# Scraping with Puppeteer

Tags: html, node.js, web, puppeteer

Background: My experience in web development has only been in creating static websites using html, css, and js.

I am developing an application as part of a school project that will extract vehicle data from various websites and subsequently display this data on my website. Users will be able to view specific vehicles within a specific region.

I've built a successful scraper in puppeteer per [these instructions](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/web-scraping-in-javascript-with-puppeteer/) that sits in scraper.js. I can view the desired results in the terminal.

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: null,
      });
    
    const trueCarURL = "https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/audi/a4/year-2017/?zip-code=Zip+Code&year=2017&vehicle-make=audi&vehicle-model=a4";
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(trueCarURL, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded", });

    // get page data
    const car = await page.evaluate(() => {
        
        // fetch the first element with the class quote
        const carList = document.querySelectorAll('.card-content');

        return Array.from(carList).map((car) => {

            const year = car.querySelector('.vehicle-card-year').innerText;
            const price = car.querySelector('.truncate:nth-child(2)').innerText;
            const makeAndModel = car.querySelector('[data-test="vehicleListingPriceAmount"]').innerText;
            const location = car.querySelector('[data-test="vehicleCardLocation"]').innerText;
            
            return{year, price, makeAndModel,location};
        });
    });
    var numVehicles = car.length;
    console.log("www.trucar.com DATA");
    console.log("Num of Vehciles in array: " + numVehicles);
    console.log(car);
   
    await browser.close();
};
```

I understand that Node.js does not interact with the DOM but I need to push the scraped data to my website. So,

I have two questions:

1. How can I push the contents of `car` to my .html file to view on the web. and
2. How can I pass the users selection into the the function from dropdown.js so that I can achieve something like this `const getCar = async (zip,year,make,model) => {}`?

Comment: This is rather broad. Can you narrow it down to a specific question and make an attempt at writing code? For #1, you can host an Express server and scrape live, or if you want a static site, write the results to a .html file and you're done--the scraping is sort of incidental, it's just data at that point. #2 depends on how you implement #1. It's not clear if you want to scrape the site live on each request or cache the results. So please make some design choices to narrow the problem down, then post when you have a concrete, specific technical code problem. Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to scrape these to a database and then have express serve that data.